# VB script fails when migrated to W7

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, windows-xp, windows-7-x64

I'm in the process of migrating a classic ASP site on an old 32bit XP server to a w7 64 bit.  The application works fine where it is currently hosted.

When migrated, I get errors in the global.asa file:

```
Sub Session_OnStart

    'works fine
    Set Session("GaoAppEnv")=Server.CreateObject("GaoCommon.AppEnv.1")
    'error
    Set Session("GaoSession")=Session("GaoAppEnv").CreateSession("file.tps")    
    ...
```

With the error:

```
Gao Subsystem error '80020009'

Unknown Exception
```

I tried to add some error catching code into the vb script around the problem area, but when I try to do WScript.Echo I get yet another error "Object required: 'WScript'"

I've added the registry settings for GaoCommon.AppEnv.1 via DLL, but file.tps seems to be only be a path in the registry to the file itself, and looks to be XML and not what I've seen for a tps filetype online.

It looks as though I've missed something in the migration over, any thoughts?

**UPDATE- Things I've already done/checked:**

- App pool is 32bit
- Registry has been updated with both file.tps and GaoCommon.AppEnv.1

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to ensure your ASP runs in a 32-bit Application Pool on the IIS Server for backward compatibility.

- Launch Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- In the Connections pane, click "Application Pools".
- Highlight the application pool for your application, then click "Advanced Settings..." in the Actions pane.
- In the "Advanced Settings" dialog, specify True for "Enable 32-Bit Applications".
- Click OK to close the "Advanced Settings" dialog.

`WScript.Echo` is only valid for VBScript under WSH (i.e. scripts executed locally on the server via `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`). To debug in ASP, you may use `Response.Write` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I enabled 32bit applications when migrating, I'll add that to my question. So there's no way of debugging there in the vb script? Any info on the initial error with `CreateSession`?